# in kendo grid column how to use autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

In a Kendo grid, how to bound the column with auto complete option in MVC web application. Want to display grid product name in autocomplete option. In that option need to bound Product item code and Product Item Name. Have any custom editor in a Kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can find one way on how to do it at [How to have an autocomplete field inside kendoUI grid using asp.net mvc wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864249/how-to-have-an-autocomplete-field-inside-kendoui-grid-using-asp-net-mvc-wrapper/24374450#24374450).  Basically you will have to create EditorTemplate and reference it from grid.

Hope this helps.