# How to properly bind autocomplete in Kendo grid MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete field for names inside a contacts grid.

A user should be able to type a name, choose one from the list, and have the other contact details populated automatically. This is working properly.

However, the user should also be able to manually enter details for a person not in the list and have them save as well. This is NOT happening. After the name field loses focus, the value is still there. After save, the value disappears because it is not properly bound to the column.

I have followed the advice (option 1, as I'd rather not use ViewData) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374450/3738893l) answer, but I cannot get the values to bind properly.

**If I name the autocomplete widget the same as the column field, the autocomplete doesn't work, the field is just a normal text field. If I name the autocomplete widget something else, the input field becomes an autocomplete field with the widgets name, but does not bind the data to the column.**

**Column Declaration**

```
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(e => e.Name).EditorTemplateName("NameLookupConcatenated");
          columns.Bound(e => e.Phone);
          columns.Bound(e => e.Email);
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
      })
```

**Grid Model**

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

**Autocomplete**

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("concatenated")
    .DataTextField("Concatenated")
    .Filter("contains")
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetUserInfo", "Contacts")
        .Data("onAdditionalData"))
        .ServerFiltering(true))
        .Events(e => e.Select("onUserSelect"))
)
```

**Autocomplete Model**

```
    public string Email { get; set; }
    private string FirstName { get; set; }
    private string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Concatenated
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }
    public string TelePhoneNo { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was already an input element on the page with the id "Name". This was causing a duplicate of the id when the grid was in edit mode and the autocomplete wasn't attached to the proper element.

My working code:

```
.Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(e => e.ConcatName).EditorTemplateName("NameLookupConcatenated"); //changed name here
          columns.Bound(e => e.Phone);
          columns.Bound(e => e.Email);
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
      })
```

Changed the name of the column above and set the "Name" property on the autocomplete to match the column name.

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("ConcatName")
.DataTextField("Concatenated")
.Filter("contains")
.DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetUserInfo", "Contacts")
    .Data("onAdditionalData"))
    .ServerFiltering(true))
    .Events(e => e.Select("onUserSelect"))
)
```