# Kendo UI Grid - How to attach a filter list to "Add New Record" option?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.net MVC project, I've an editable Kendo grid as shown below:

[image: Editable Kendo Grid]

The grid displays data from a model and is working fine for its usual operations.

Now, I want to add a filter to the "Add New Record" option on the User ID column. When the user types a user ID, I want to filter it against a list of user IDs stored in an separate list (not part of the grid/ model). I'm not sure how to do this.

I think I have to bind the 'keyup' function of the userID column, but just can't figure out how to apply the filter to get the values from the separate list. What I've done so far for this is:

```
@{
    var userIDs = ViewData["SalesUserIDs"];
}

$("#UserID").bind("keyup", function () {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(this).filter(function () {
        return userIDs .toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == 0;
    }).show();
});
```

I'm not sure about the bind function.

Comment: Why not just use a kendo autocomplete control? http://jsbin.com/ohimef/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Doesn't it require the data from the grid?

Comment: Can do either. This example builds its own, separate, datasource.

Comment: You are using "editor: serviceItemAutoCompleteEditor" in your code. Any idea what the equivalent in asp.net razor implementation would be for this in Kendo?

Comment: Use an editor template. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864249/how-to-have-an-autocomplete-field-inside-kendoui-grid-using-asp-net-mvc-wrapper/24374450#24374450

Comment: What you are looking for is not a filter. You need an auto-complete or a combo-box.

Comment: @SteveGreene That worked. Thanks.